# What is the complication behind a simple counting problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there is a circular table where $n$ people sits around. How many ways can you choose three consecutive people ?

Approach 1: just by drawing it out we see there are $n$ ways to do so.

Approach 2: First there are $n$ choices for the first people, 2 choices for the second(to choose the second around the first), then 2 choices for the last. Observe that any three consecutive people are chosen 4 times. To see this is true, consider
"123,312,213,321" where 1 stands for the first choice, 2 stand for the second, 3 for the third.

Approach 3: First there are $n$ choices for the first people, 4 choices for the second(two positions right to the first and two positions to the left.) Now, for the thirds choice, we have some case work. If the second person is the neighbor to the first people(2 choices for the second person), we have 2 choices for the third. If the second person is not the immediate neighbor to the first, in other words, there is one position in between them(2 choices to choose the second), the third must be chosen between them, so 1 choice only. We the have $n\cdot(2\cdot 2+2\cdot 1)=6n$ 
Observe that given any three consecutive people, we've counted them 6 times as $3!=6$. This is because in this case all permutations are chosen.

All solutions lead us to n, and they are all correct I guess.(at least the first one.) Now, the question rises, in the second and the third approach, how do you know that at the initial count, you've counted all the possible cases. I mean, how do you know if the 4n in the second or 6n in the third covered all cases?(do not bother with the over counting yet). It is really a question that is tough to express. Please comment if you didn't get my question. I appreciate your time and help!

Comment: What about 231 and 132?

Comment: They cannot be selected in the second approach because we said the second choice has to be the neighbor of the first. in case of "231", 3 is in the middle of 2 and 1 which is impossible. In approach three it is valid.

Comment: Does the order in which we choose the people matter or are we choosing the three people as a set?

Comment: Oh, we are definitely choosing a set. We said choose three consecutive people where you should consider three consecutive people as a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three people are completely determined by the leftmost person in clockwise or counterclockwise order (which you choose doesn't matter). There are $n$ choices for the leftmost person, and the other two are completely determined by this choice.

Comment: Yeah, I know, this approach certainly works, its just the first approach. I am asking about the second or third approach. How do I know if I've covered all possibilities by constructing like that?